# Firestore Rules, request.auth.uid is not the same as uid I get from firebase auth google signin

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Confused about firestore security rules.

I'm using a cordova plugin: `cordova-plugin-firebasex` to authenticate and handle storing user data in firestore.

My firestore structure is as follows:

`firestore database > collection: [uid] > bunch of documents`

I store user data by creating a collection with the authenticated `User UID` as seen in the `Authentication > Users` panel of Firebase Authentication console.

However when I create the following rules. they always resolve to false. Even when I manually put the UID string in to replace `userId` > `allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == <copied User UID>;` it resolves to false.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database} {
    match /{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
thanks @doug for pointing out the document wild cards.

The working rules are as follows: (notice `/databases/{database}/documents` <- documents was missing) and wildcard added in collection

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's not a good idea from a modeling perspective to give each user their own top-level collection.  You should instead give them each a document in a single collection (say, "users") then give them subcollecitons under that as needed.  You will probably understand why this after you use Firestore for a while, but even if you don't understand now, I suggest you change it to closer to what you see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication).

The rule you have now doesn't work because it doesn't match any documents.  You need at least two components to match a document.  If you want to match all documents in a collection, you will need another wildcard for that:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database} {
    match /{userId}/{docId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Doug, Thanks for the response. I tried what you did but it still didn't work. even with wildcard: `match /{userId}/{document=**}` the reason I didn't do it as sub collection was because the `cordova-plugin-firebasex` specifies: "Only top-level Firestore collections are currently supported - subcollections (nested collections within documents) are currently not supported due to the complexity of mapping the native objects into the plugin's JS API layer." could it be the auth doesn't like the collection being the userID?

Comment: Hi @Doug, I just noticed something crucial, for some reason my rules were missing `/documents` in `match /databases/{database} {`
What i've got now works!
Correct syntax updated in the post:

Answer (score 0):

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /users/{userId} {
            allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
            allow create: if request.auth != null;
        }
    }
}
```

For more: [Writing conditions for Cloud Firestore Security Rules (Firebase Documentation)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions)